# Top 30 Songs using Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, post-meta

I have successfully created a Top 30 songs ranking via custom post type. Now im stuck with adding "Peak Position" post meta. I don't know how to program it. Peak Position is the position where the song ranked for a couple of weeks.

For example, Song 1 has been ranked 5 for 10 weeks and then down to 6 position for 3 weeks.. so the Peak Position for Song 1 is 5 since it lasted for 10 weeks.

Now i'm stucked thinking how can i save its peak position using post meta.

Can anyone suggest?

Comment: How is that Peak Position defined? Does it only relate to how many weeks the song has been in that position. Or only the highest position ever, no matter how many weeks.

Comment: Do you have a currently working code? Could you post what you already have?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, that Peak Postion is based on longest period the song was in same position (which I found odd), here's what you could do:

- Have three meta fields
  :: song_meta_peak
  :: song_meta_weeks_now
  :: song_meta_weeks_peak
- First time song enters the list, you set `peak` meta to whatever the position is and both `weeks_now` and `weeks_peak` metas to `1`
- Every week, if position is not changed, you add 1 to `weeks_now` meta
- Whenever the position changes you first check the `weeks_now` meta to find out how long the song has been in the previous position, and if it exceeds the `weeks_peak` you set `peak` meta to that previous position and override `weeks_peak` to match the `weeks_now`. After that you set `weeks_now` back to `1`.

Hope that helps

**Code Example**

```
$oldWeeks = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'song_meta_weeks_now', true );
$oldWeeksPeak = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'song_meta_weeks_peak', true );

if ( POS. NOT CHANGED ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'song_meta_weeks_now', $oldWeeks + 1 );
} else {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'song_meta_weeks_now', 1 );
    if ( $oldWeeks > $oldWeeksPeak ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'song_meta_weeks_peak', $oldWeeks );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'song_meta_peak', PREVIOUS POS. );
    }
}
```